# Op-Amp Comparator precision voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I need to trigger a speaker if my input voltage is higher than 0.6 V, otherwise the speaker must not be triggered. That's the reason I'm using an AMPOP Comparator:

[image]

and, as far as I know, the voltage Vout should be:

$$  V_{\text{out}} = \begin{cases} V_{\text{S}+} & \text{if } V_1 > V_2, \\ V_{\text{S}-} & \text{if } V_1 < V_2, \\ 0 & \text{if } V_1 = V_2\end{cases}$$

But when I simulate my circuit, my output voltage is not Vs+ or Vs-. There is a loss in voltage and you can check all voltages on the following image.

[image]

V1 = 1 V and V2 = 0.6 V, Vout = 13.011, but Vs+ = 15 V;

[image]

V1 = 0.2 V and V2 = 0.6, Vout = 1.9889, but Vs- = 0 V.

I need Vout near 15 V (and 0 V if V1 < V2). It doesn't have to be exactly 15 volts, but near it. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to do it without another amplifier after the output? I'm beginner sorry if I misunderstood something.

BTW, if you know an easier way to trigger the speaker, tell me ;)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "triggering" a speaker, nor why you think a op-amp wired as a comparator will do that.  But, the output voltages you see are easily explained by the fact that many op-amps have a compliance voltage in that range... that is, the outputs can not drive the whole supply range... compliance of ~2V is not unusual. Read your datasheet!  You don't mention what op-amp you are using. A "rail-to-rail" op amp will drive the output closer to the rail voltages.  Even better, use a dedicated comparator IC for this function.

Comment: @BPete, good enough for an answer, I think.

Comment: Why you need 15V or a DC signal on a speaker that would imply 2 Amps (but not deliver) in the speaker coil is beyond me. But you can't create a tertiary level output window detector with a simple comparator.. try again?

Comment: @Richman: Good points.  We could use some detail about what the poster is trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want an alarm system. If the voltage goes over 0.6 volts, the speaker is activated, otherwise no sound.

Comment: As my Vs- = 0 volts, I need 0 volts as output voltage if my input voltage is lower than 0.6 volts... To not trigger the alarm

Answer (score 1):

*Do you even need +15V to -15V output???*

Power on the speaker is ~Vpeak^2/R, so for an 8 ohm coil this system will blast out 15^2/8 ~= 28 Watts, which is pretty loud.  Also placing DC current through a speaker is bad for it.

If you wanna stick with this design: you're going to need a Comparator with Rail-Rail operation, and even then that only gets you to Vdd-0.3V and Vss+0.3V .  Check to see if this suits your needs.  Since you are also driving a speaker, use Ohm's law on the speaker impedance to figure out how much current you're gonna need.  An 8 ohm speaker will need at least a 2 Amp power supply for both +15 V and -15V. Best bet is to drive the system with +-18V 3A Rails. Find a comparator that can handle +-15V outputs, and get an output buffer that can handle 2 Amps both ways.